# syncronizing Backlog Priority between Azure DevOps and Aha

Tags: azure-devops, synchronization, rank, backlog

I'm trying to understand how to set up my two tools to work together seamlessly.  When I prioritize the backlog as a Product Leader, I want to preserve that order when it moves to Azure DevOps using the Aha API.  but this just adds everything to the bottom of an order list in Aha.  I sync the Rank in Aha to the Stack Rank both ways from Aha to ADO, but I'm not getting it to go both ways.  when the Rank comes from Aha to ADO it's a single #, ie 1, 2, 3, 4 showing the order.  If I have that order and 'reorder it' the #'s change from 1, 2, 3, 4 into values that are still in a rank order, but not so obvious and the Rank in Aha doesn't update to reflect the new stack rank in ADO.  Any suggestions of how to complete this two-way sync to preserve order and not cause manual updates by Product would be great.

[Order in Aha](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayxQl.png)

[Order in ADO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyaGM.png)

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question, If yes, you could accept it as an answer(https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks. If not, please let us know if you would like further assistance

Answer (score 0):

we do not have any feature to help us set up these two tools to work together seamlessly. We need to manually update the order list.